# SQL - table with multiple rows

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I have table like this:

`news_to_category`

| news_id | category_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 5 | 4 |

And now I need to get all `news_id` containing `category_id` equals `1` and `2`, so the result should be:

1, 2, 3, 4

(news `5` has `2` category, but doesn't have `1` category)

How can I create SQL for this problem.

#mysql

I have tried

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM 
news_to_category 
WHERE news_id IN (SELECT 
                 DISTINCT 
                 FROM news_to_category 
                 WHERE category_id = 1) 
AND news_id IN (SELECT 
                 DISTINCT 
                 FROM 
                 news_to_category 
                 WHERE category_id = 2)
```

Comment: `WITH cte AS ( SELECT news_id, COUNT( CASE WHEN category_id = 1 THEN 1 END ) AS CountCat1, COUNT( CASE WHEN category_id = 2 THEN 1 END ) AS CountCat2  FROM news_to_category GROUP BY news_id ) SELECT DISTINCT news_id FROM cte WHERE CountCat1 > 0 AND CountCat2 > 0`

Comment: that's works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Common logical division:

```
SELECT news_id
FROM news_to_category
WHERE category_id IN (1, 2)            -- categories list
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT category_id) = 2 -- categories list length
```

If `(news_id, category_id)` is defined as UNIQUE then DISTINCT can be removed.

Comment: that's works, thanks

Answer (score -2):

Try this one:

SELECT * FROM news_to_category
WHERE category_id IN (1,2)
GROUPBY news_id

Comment: This doesn't solve the OP's question; instead it returns incorrect (and non-distinct) results. The `WHERE x IN ( ... )` operator does not do what you think it does - and you can't use `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: unfortunately not working